# Declaring function in definitions file not read

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a definition file with this code:

```
declare function $$(el: string): Element;
```

I reference that definitions file from a main.ts file, but the name `$$` is not found.
How does it work?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Can you update the post with the exact files you have? Or do you mean it's not found during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

> How does it work?

Add a tsconfig.json and explicitly list the file in the `files` to be very sure. It definitely should work.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/compilation-context.html